# Theorem in Morse Theory about connections through a saddle point

Tags: morse-theory

I was talking to a professor about Morse theory and he said that there a result similar to:

> Two bodies of water in a domain that are currently not connected will
>   connect across a saddle point.

I cannot remember if this was a result of the mountain pass lemma or of some theory in Morse theory (We were chatting about many different things). This is not my area of math and I was hoping someone could point me to a theory statement like this somewhere so I can read more about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the domain is non-degenerate you can prove this through Morse theory. If you don't know that the critical points are non-degenerate it is a bit harder to say what a saddle point is: but the mountain pass lemma will provide a critical point which has saddle like behavior. Anyway to prove this in the non-degenerate situation you should play around with the morse relations:

Let $c_i$ be the critical poins of index $i$ and $b_i$ the betti numbers. If your domain is connected $b_0=1$ and some sublevel set is not then $c_0\geq 2$. Then the second morse relation states

$$
c_1-c_0\geq b_1-b_0
$$
So
$c_1\geq b_1+c_0-b_0\geq 1.$

Hence there must be a critical point of index $1$, i.e. there is a saddle.